# Play without bots in the team

Tags: counter-strike-global-offensive

I along with my three other friends play Counter Strike: Global Offensive using LAN. I just want us to be in a team instead of 4 players + 1 bot. Is there any command to enable this feature?

Answer (score 2):

bot_quota 0 Remove all bots 
If you want to play against 4 bots, then bot_quota 4 should do the trick.

But i recommend you guys play 2V2 or Cue on matchmaking. Bots are only so good and are good to get to know the game, but after that they are NOTHING like a real player.

Here are some other bot commands for you (with info - what they do)
http://wiki.multiplay.co.uk/CSGO/Bot_Commands

Answer (score 1):

try bot_kick, then you should be able to bot_add_ct/bot_add_t depending on how many people you want to add, you also want to mp_limitteams 10/20, whatever you want and keep on adding.

Comment: bot_kick_all otherwise the game adds new bots in-place of the kicked one ...